# Heroku: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, python-2.7

How do I use my production settings with heroku? This is my first attempt at any project deployment that I created ever, so I may be doing things completely wrong. I have a settings.py file and a settings_production file, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the production settings to work. I tried changing my manage.py from

```
"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings"
```

to

```
"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings_production"
```

then using the commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "production settings"
```

and I have also just tried changing DEBUG to False in my settings.py file. How do you commit changes to your settings in heroku or point to the correct file? I was able to get through the tutorial successfully, but I have not had luck trying to deploy my project.  Also, should there be code that I add to manage.py that checks if it is a production or develop environment and uses the correct settings file accordingly, or do I manually change it? Still learning so I could be doing it completely wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Heroku, [you can configure environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) - they are called config vars.

The `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable should be set to `myproject.settings_production`.

---

Your `manage.py` is probably not being run in Heroku (there are other ways to run a Django app), which is why your change didn't work.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed to do the trick, however the app still won't open and there are several other warnings in the logs. any idea about WARNING/MainProcess] celery@ce7e5946-3bc3-4622-856f-863b49f442d4 ready, WARNING/Beat] Reset: Account for new __version__ field, WARNING/Beat] Reset: Account for utc_enabled field, or WARNING/Beat] Reset: Account for new tz field??

Comment: @GetItDone You should create another question with the new issues you are having : )

Comment: Ok I will try to figure them out first, and if I can't I will. Thanks!